# Gardening Anniversary Contest

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Hello Gardening & Langscaping users! Following my last [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387/ideas-for-gardening-landscapings-anniversary-contest) asking for contest ideas, here's what we've come up with:

1. The contest will start on 1st of August UTC (tomorrow) and last for 4 weeks, until 22 August.
2. Every week, 2 winners will be selected, one each for:

   - asking a question with the highest number of views
   - posting an answer with the highest score

   The question/answer must be posted during that week for it to be eligible. So get to sharing, and don't forget to upvote good answers!
3. Winners get to choose one of the following as their prize: a waterbottle, SE t-shirt or an SE mug.

We'll announce the winners each week in answers, and the moderator team will privately compile contact/shipping info for prizes. (Good news: SE ships internationally!)

### Additional notes:

- Closed and deleted posts are ineligible for the event.
- Winning one week makes you ineligible to win again. Somewhat harsh, I know, but we'd like to reach as many people as we can.

Good luck, everyone!

Comment: Thanks for participating in this contest, everyone! The winners will be emailed soon. :)

Comment: Thanks to SE, Aarthi and Rebecca Chernoff too on behalf of [gardening.se]!

Comment: @yoda and waxeagle: Thanks for setting it up!

Answer (score 2):

Week one winners:

- Top Viewed Question: [Why do people paint some tree trunks white at the bottom?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/why-do-people-paint-some-tree-trunks-white-at-the-bottom)
- Top Scoring Answer: [Why do people paint some tree trunks white at the bottom?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/why-do-people-paint-some-tree-trunks-white-at-the-bottom/4945#4945)

Answer (score 2):

Week two winners:

- Top Viewed Question: [How is 'gardening soil' made?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/how-is-gardening-soil-made)
- Top Scoring Answer: [What is this plant that resembles tomato and has small dark fruit?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/what-is-this-plant-that-resembles-tomato-and-has-small-dark-fruit/4957#4957)

Answer (score 1):

Week three winners:

- Top Viewed Question: [What is the difference between compost and soil?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/what-is-the-difference-between-compost-and-soil)
- Top Scoring Answer: [What causes mildew on plants and how to prevent it?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5023/what-causes-mildew-on-plants-and-how-to-prevent-it/5024#5024)

Comment: Original answer winner was a repeat, hence the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Week four winners:

- Top Viewed Question: [Colorado Plant/Weed Identification Thistle thing with purple flowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/colorado-plant-weed-identification-thistle-thing-with-purple-flowers)
- Top Scoring Answer: [Colorado Plant/Weed Identification Thistle thing with purple flowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/colorado-plant-weed-identification-thistle-thing-with-purple-flowers/5065#5065)

Comment: Note: Top Scoring answer isn't the *overall* winner, but rather the first unique winner. Bamboo was 3/5 of the top answers for this past week, but had won for last week.